# placment of classes in NerdDinner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, viewmodel, nerddinner

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and looking at the ASP.NET MVC sample application [NerdDinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/).

1. The folder "Models" contains a class called `Dinner.cs`. This is the main Dinner entity.
   Shouldn't this class be in an other location? For example "Domain" ? And instead should a viewmodel class be put in the Models folder that contains dinner information?
2. Why is the file "PaginatedList.cs" located in the folder called: "Helpers". Shouldn't this file be in the folder: "Models" since it is supplied to views?

Any clearification on this would realy be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure, your thinking is right about this. NerdDinner is made just for concept-presentation purposes and doesn't really pretends to all the best practices. It becomes more and more obvious as your own project grows. You will have your domain entities/services/repositories in separate folder, then separate project, then possibly separate solution. You will find yourself renamed this folder to `ViewModels` to make it more obvious for other people working on project.
2. PaginatedList can be a ViewModel and contain data related to pagination. Then it can be put to `ViewModels` folder. But I believe what you have in NerdDinner - is just a simple View helper to generate pagination markup. Moreover, helpers could be not that strict "View" or "ViewModel" - they can contain simple logic, they're somewhat in the middle :) between View and ViewModel. Also note that PaginatedList is more of a "framework" concern than of a "particular solution". So you can't place it to "Views" or "Models" folder amongst project-specific things. So "Helpers" is good enough for NerdDinner. In a real solution you'd better make it common, include it into your "framework" that is on top of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

for the first question, the `Dinner.cs` file contains a partial of the `Dinner` class along with some validation attributes on a buddy class. It's perfectly sane, IMHO, to put this file into the `Model` folder, since it's actually part of the solution's model.

for your second question, the `PaginatedList` is kind of a data structure which allows you to view a certain "page" of your data (a fixed set of elements) at a time. I don't really see it being a `ViewModel`, a "helper" is exactly what it is.

One more thing I would like to add is, if you have some ViewModels that you pass in to your views instead of the actual model classes, or because you have a specific set of data elements to pass, I think it would be reasonable to have a separate `ViewModel` folder for that.

Hope this helps :)